# Demonstrate the existence of the following limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Prove that for $m \geq n \geq 1$ that $|a_m-a_n| \leq n^{-1}$ and deduce that $(a_n)$ converges. For $n\in \mathbb{N}$, denote

$$a_n=\int\limits_1^n\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2}dx.$$

By integration by parts, or otherwise, demonstrate the existence of

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int\limits_1^n\frac{\sin(x)}xdx$$

I have done everything but the last part. No idea how to proceeed.

Comment: Let $u=1/x$ and $dv=\sin x\,dx$.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, for $m \geq n$,
$$|a_n-a_m| = \left| \int_n^m \frac{\cos x}{x^2} dx\right| \leq \int_n^m \frac{| \cos x|}{x^2} dx \leq \int_n^m \frac{1}{x^2} dx=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m} \leq \frac{1}{n}$$

so $(a_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence, hence convergent. Let $L$ be its limit.

For the second part, integrating by parts,

$$\int_1^n\frac{\sin x}{x} dx = \left[ \frac{- \cos x}{x} \right]_1^n - \int_1^n \frac{ \cos x}{x^2} dx$$

So
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \int_1^n\frac{\sin x}{x} dx = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \cos 1 - \frac{\cos n}{n} - a_n = \cos 1 -0 -L$$

So the integral converges.